# How to write post to my FB fan page from my own website

Tags: php, facebook

In my Admin panel on site i can upload photo... I want make form where i must write post and upload photo.

When i write some post and upload some photo, it save photo to server and save post to database.
I ALLREADY HAVE THIS.

And i want do this:
When it save photo and save post, it shoud log me to facebook and send post to site where Im admin.

Prease look to this image

I

I

V

[image]

And now: can you help me pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge of the facebook API (which granted is not fluent) this isn't exactly possible, it'd be a pretty big security risk.